# Theorem Explanation: Sequences and Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I'm currently studying analysis and came across this theorem:

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $x \in {\Bbb R}$. If $(a_n)$ is a
sequence of positive real numbers with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a_n} =0$ and if for some constant $C > 0$ and some $m \in {\Bbb N}$ we have:
$|x_n - x| \leq Ca_n$ $\forall n \geq m$ then:

$\lim{x_n}  = x$ as $ x \to \infty$

I don't understand what the theorem means so I can't even begin to start constructing a proof for it. I've read the statement over and over again, however, I just can't make sense of it. Can anyone please explain what this theorem is saying?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a different version of the squeeze theorem. It is basically saying that since we know that $a_n$ gets really small as $n \to \infty$, if we know that there is a constant $C> 0$ such that $|x-x_n| \leq Ca_n$ (the distance between $x_n$ and $x$ is a multiple of how close $a_n$ is to $0$ since $a_n = |a_n - 0|$) then $x_n$ gets really close to $x$ as $n\to \infty$.

Example: We know that $a_n = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Since 
$$\left|\frac{5n^2 + n}{n^2 + n^{1/2} + 1} - 5\right| \leq \frac{3}{n},$$ (you can check by a calculation) for $n \geq 25 = m$.
If we write $x_n = \frac{5n^2 + n}{n^2 + n^{1/2} + 1}$ and $x = 5$, then
$$|x_n - x| = \left|\frac{5n^2 + n}{n^2 + n^{1/2} + 1} - 5\right| \leq \frac{3}{n} = 3a_n =Ca_n,$$ and so
 the theorem that you are wanting to prove says that $x_n \to x$.

Comment: Thank you! However, I don't understand how 4/n became 3/n?

Comment: Thank you! However, I don't understand how 4/n became 3/n?

Comment: It didn't... it's a typo. It should just be $3/n$. I will fix it.

Comment: Thank you. It's starting to make a bit more sense.

Comment: One point is that whether or not $x_n\to x$ is unaffected by $\{x_n:n\in M\}$  for any given $finite $ $ M$.  Another point is that $x_n\to x$ iff $\frac {1}{C}x_n\to \frac {1}{C}x$ for any $C\ne 0.$ For example if $p_1(x) , p_2(x)$ are polynomials of degree $d_1, d_2 $ respectively, with $n_1<n_2,$  then we may use this to show that 
 $p_1(n)/p_2(n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty. $